# When adding a button inside an Angular Material table, the column with sticky becomes transparent

Tags: html, angular

When I add a button in each cell in an Angular Material table, the background of the sticky becomes transparent. I’ve been trying to create some CSS classes to solve it but I haven’t been able to. I would like to know if there is a way to do it from HTML without needing to use CSS.

`<button mat-button> {{ element[column] }}</button>`

[image]

Comment: please share the code if possible a stackblitz relicating the issue and finally the expected output!